# Hide a specific workbook via userform in vba

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2013

I have a userform with 2 command buttons : hide and show.

This work if I only have 1 workbook open. I can simply hide and show the workbook from the form.  However If I have another workbook open let say Book1. and then I click Hide, It will also hide the Book1.  I want only to hide the specific workbook.

Here's my code:

```
Private Sub cmdHide_Click()

'ThisWorkbook("hide_sheet").
Application.Visible = False

End Sub

Private Sub cmdShow_Click()

'ThisWorkbook("hide_sheet").
Application.Visible = True


End Sub
```

Comment: You need to specify the workbooks and worksheets. When you open another one, it becomes `ThisWorkbook`. Or, do `If ThisWorkbook.Name = "firstWorkBook" Then Thisworkbook.hide` or something.

Comment: If ThisWorkbook.Name = "hide_sheet" Then

ThisWorkbook.Hide

End If

Comment: Still not working Sir..I'd been searching this online but with no good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Should be something like this*

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub cmdHide_Click()
    'ThisWorkbook("hide_sheet").
    Workbooks("Book1.xlsx").Windows(1).Visible = False
End Sub

Private Sub cmdShow_Click()
    'ThisWorkbook("hide_sheet").
    Workbooks("Book1.xlsx").Windows(1).Visible = True
End Sub
```

*Another Example that work on both Excel 2010 & 2013*

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub cmdHide_Click()
    'ThisWorkbook("hide_sheet").
    Windows(ThisWorkbook.Name).Visible = False
End Sub

Private Sub cmdShow_Click()
    'ThisWorkbook("hide_sheet").
    Windows(ThisWorkbook.Name).Visible = True
End Sub
```

Comment: @BambooLikeFox Did you update with correct `Book1.xlsx` name?

Comment: yes..that workbook name is my current workbook that I wanted to hide...mine is hide_sheet.xlsx

Comment: Which office are you using?

Comment: office pro 2013..the 1st code that i used only works if I only have one workbook open..

Comment: It makes the Sheet turn into gray..I wanted to be able to really hide the whole workbook.  I'm currently running 2 macro file and the 1st one has this hide/show optionbutton content.  if i choose hide, it will also hide the other workbook.

Comment: @BambooLikeFox see the second example - both work on 2010 & 2013,